# Find images by size: find / file / awk

Tags: files, find, awk, xargs, images

I've been trying to find png image files a certain height (over 500px).  I know that `file` will return image dimensions.  Example:

```
$ file TestImg1a.png

TestImg1a.png: PNG image data, 764 x 200, 4-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

But I need to use this to find all files in a directory with a height over 500px.  I know how to print out all files regardless of height:

```
find . -name '*.png' | xargs file | awk '{print $7 " " $1}'
```

But how do I limit the $7 to those results greater than 500?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i know this is a bit overkill but, this will work every time (even if there are spaces in your filename) and regardless of how file displays the information.

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*png\): .* \([0-9]* x [0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk 'int($1) > 500 {print}'
```

and it prints the dimensions of the picture and the file

explaination:

1. `find` all files named *.png under . and for each do a file on it
2. use `sed` to print only the filename and dimensions then re-order to print dimensions first
3. use `awk` to test the first number (height of pic) making sure its greater than 500 and if it is print dimensions and file name, if not do nothing.

Comment: Thanks.  I did have to make a slight change -- the $1 in the awk argument to $3.  But this definitely got it for me.

Answer (score 13):

```
exiftool -q -r -ext png -if '$ImageHeight > 500' -p '$Directory/$FileName' .
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `identify` from ImageMagick:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0|xargs -0 identify -format '%h %f\n'|
awk '$1>500'|cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Or in OS X:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName=*.png&&kMDItemPixelHeight>500' -onlyin .
```

Answer (score 5):

I feel that something other than shell utilities would be more appropriate, e.g., Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;
use Image::Info qw(image_info dim);

find (\&check_height, './');

sub check_height {

  my $info = image_info( $_ );
  my ($width, $height) = dim( $info );
  print $_ . " has height $height\n" if ( $height > 500 );

}
```

Less dicking around with trying to parse out $7; just get the dimensions directly.  Yes, you'll need the Image::Info module, but, on CentOS/RHEL, it's a standard package, so you can just run `yum install perl-Image-Info`.

Comment: While perl is a normally a great solution, it's not in this case, esp since I don't have Image::Info nor the option to install.

Comment: The perl solution is somewhat faster than the find/file/awk one, which is nice, and on ubuntu derivates the image info module is available from `apt-get install libimage-info-perl`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec file "{}" \+ | awk -F"(: +PNG image data|,| x )" '$4 > 500 {print $4" "$1}'
```

Comment: doesn't work: `96, ./4/45445106_w185.png:
86, ./4/404358x_w185.png:
86, ./4/404341x_w185.png:
80, ./4/475986_w185.png:
621, ./4/481693_w185.png:
667, ./4/42513x_w185.png:
86, ./4/404372x_w185.png:`

Comment: @tink, cast $7 to an int before comparison, i.e. int($7) > 500.. in the absence of casting awk is resorting to a literal string compare

Comment: Steve, where does that "," come from? My "file" doesn't produce that.  But as Chandra said: you can explicitly force $7 to become an integer using the method pointed out in his comment.

Comment: your awk statement will only work if the filename has no spaces in it

Comment: @tink the "," is part of what file returns in my environment.

Comment: @h3rrmiller requiring the ability for filenames with spaces is not a concern and was not included in the question.  But thanks for pointing that out for the future.

Comment: I know it wasn't but you never know :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will also work. The last part of the code (`mv "$img" ./lowpixel`) will move files below a specified width and height to a folder. In the following example all jpg images lower than 300x300 will be moved to a folder named `lowpixel`:

`find -iname \*.jpg | while read img; do anytopnm "$img" | pamfile | perl -ane 'exit 1 if $F[3]<300 || $F[5]<300' || mv "$img" ./lowpixel; done`